# Node.JS Big-Endian UCS-2

Tags: javascript, unicode, node.js, buffer, endianness

I'm working with Node.JS.  [Node's buffers](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffers.html#buffers) support little-endian UCS-2, but not big-endian, which I need.  How would I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to wikipedia, [UCS-2 should always be big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2#Byte_order_encoding_schemes) so it's odd that node only supports little endian.  You might consider filing a bug.  That said, switching endian-ness is fairly straight-forward since it's just a matter of byte order.  So just swap bytes around to go back and forth between little and big endian, like so:

```
function swapBytes(buffer) {
  var l = buffer.length;
  if (l & 0x01) {
    throw new Error('Buffer length must be even');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
    var a = buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
    buffer[i+1] = a;
  }
  return buffer; 
}
```

Comment: That's about what I ended up doing.  I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Or not...apparently they don't like that.  https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1684