# Support [ and ] characters in PDU mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, gsm

I am writing application in nodejs for sending and recieving sms in PDU mode.I use wavecom GSM modem(7-bit encoding) to send sms. It also support 8 bit(AT+CSMP=1,167,0,8) encoding scheme.

I can send alpha numeric character properly.But I can't send some character like ([,],| etc).

Here string :

```
AT+CMGS=14    
0001030C911989890878800004015B
```

Text String : `[`

But I recieve some junk character. Any Idea?

And how to send multipart sms. I have refer [this](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/), and [this](http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/) but I does not get desired output. can anyone suggest 8-bit([7-bit encoding scheme](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/hello.html)) text encoding scheme?
Please Help me...

Comment: have you tried escaping the characters yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks,

Finally I got the answer :)

This characters([,],|) are encode as two characters like

`[` is encode as `1B1E` (Combination of escape character and < sign)

`]` is encode as `1B20` (Combination of escap character and > sign)

So whenever I fond such characters I replaced it with corresponding value then I use 7 bit encoding. It's Work good...

So my encoding string for [ is

```
> AT+CMGS=15
> 0001000C911989890878800000021B1E
```

And for "[hello]"

```
> AT+CMGS=21
> 0001000C911989890878800000091B1EBACC66BF373E
```

Thanks once again..

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/) (see section Sending an Unicode SMS message), the 8bit encoding is in fact UCS-2.

I don't know enough about nodejs to give you the full implementation, but here is a .NET sample:

```
string EncodeSmsText(string text)
{
    // Convert input string to a sequence of bytes in BigEndian UCS-2 encoding
    //    'Hi' -> [0, 72, 0, 105]
    var bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(text);

    // Encode bytes to hex representation
    //    [0, 72, 0, 105] -> '00480069'
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Please note that according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438340/convert-to-ucs2) my code will not work for characters encoded as surrogate pairs, because `Encoding.BigEndianEncoding` is UTF-16 (not UCS-2).

**Edit**

Here is NodeJS version that uses the built-in UCS2 converter in Buffer class:

```
function swapBytes(buffer) {
    var l = buffer.length;
    if (l & 0x01) {
        throw new Error('Buffer length must be even');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        var a = buffer[i];
        buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
        buffer[i+1] = a;
    }
    return buffer; 
}

function encodeSmsText(input) {
    var ucs2le = new Buffer(input, 'ucs2');
    var ucs2be = swapBytes(ucs2le);
    return ucs2be.toString('hex');

}

console.log(encodeSmsText('Hi'));
```

Inspired by these SO answers:

- [Node.JS Big-Endian UCS-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459332/node-js-big-endian-ucs-2)
- [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly with Gammy SMS gateway.